# why onStartCommand() is used in Service?

Tags: android, service

I'm a bit confusion using service where I do implement `onStartCommand().`  In some example onStartcommand() method is implemented and somewhere not. For what I need to use this method can u please clarify my doubt.

Answer (score 2):

The Android documentation says that `onStartCommand()` is:

> Called by the system every time a client explicitly starts the service
>   by calling startService(Intent), providing the arguments it supplied
>   and a unique integer token representing the start request. Do not call
>   this method directly

Answer (score 1):

`onStartCommand` is used to pass on commands (intent) to service. It can be called as many times as you want. However, `onCreate` is called only once, guaranteeing that the service is created.

Answer (score 1):

The `onStartCommand()` is called when you start the service using the `startService()` method.  You never start the service yourself, but request that the given service is started, using an intent.

Some examples use the `bindService()` method instead of the `startService()` method (you can also use both). A bound service runs only as long as another application component is bound to it.

Usually, a started service performs a single operation and does not return a result to the caller.

Answer (score 0):

you should implement the onStartCommand() method in your service when you want to define the behavior of your service when it's started and when you want to control how it should behave when restarted or if it's killed by the system. If your service doesn't require custom behavior on start or restart, you can omit this method, and the default behavior will be applied based on the service's return value.

Comment: Answer is hard to read. Pleas use proper grammar to make it easier to understand and increase readability.